# Skin disappeared after installing Xcode 6 iOS Simulator 8

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, frame, skin

After installing Xcode 6 I got the new version of the iOS Simulator.

Unfortunately, the nice iPhone skin/frame is gone. It was great for taking screenshots.

How get I get it back to work?

Yes, I have a Retina MB 15” and yes, the scale is on 100%.

Comment: any iphone simulator file-> save sceren shot allows to make screen shots. I suppose under nice iphone simulator you mean iphone 3 gs simulator with ios 6.1. Unfortunately xcode 6 does not support it.

Comment: Came across this again after answering it two years ago. Upvoting because of the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don’t use the simulator for device screenshots. Apple provides hi-res Photoshop files that have placeholders for your screenshots. Their status bars are also perfect, App Store-ready 9:41 AM works of art :)

Link: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#images

Update: you can also use [frameit](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/frameit) from Fastlane to automate this.

Comment: Agreed. It would be nice if the simulator had a "spit out App Store-ready screenshots" button. I have previously filed two related radars: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5888391438663680 and http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5144348618391552